# Unexpected behaviour in std::transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a `std::vector<float> vertices` which I want to transform and append the results onto the vector; I have done this so far:

```
std::transform(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), std::back_inserter(vertices), [index = 0,&sideDim] (float ver) mutable{
                    return ver + 1;
                });
```

but I seem to get a floating point value of `-1.998397116e+18` for each of the new inserts. Why is this?

Comment: When you append an element to the container, the `end` iterator becomes invalid.

Comment: Why do you capture `index` and `sideDim`? And why do you make the lambda `mutable`?

Comment: It is not so clear what you want to do. May you post an example with some numbers?

Comment: Please post a [mre], if the capacity of your vector increases during transform the iterators you've passed in become invalid

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertices.reserve(vertices.size()*2)` on the previous line.

Your back inserting is invalidating your iterators and reallocating the buffer you are reading from.  So you get garbage.

The code you posted also might not be doing what you want to do, but that fixes the UB in the code posted.